# Two date columns comparing with system date

Tags: sql, sql-server

Two date columns need to compare with current system date, if those falls into it, display into table[image]

Comment: Use `between` to filter, then pivot.

Comment: And also present your data as text not images so it can be copied out for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working with dates, so I suspect you want:

```
where start_date <= convert(date, getdate()) and
      end_date >= convert(date, getdate())
```